# Weird issue, translations works if logged in, if not then didn't work in Symfony 2.5.6

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation, fosuserbundle

I come here with this weird issue around Symfony2 translations since I don't know what else to do. As title says "translations works if a user is logged in, otherwise doesn't. Here is what I've done:

1. Set default locale and translator at `config.yml`:

   ```
   framework:
       translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
       default_locale:  "%locale%"
   ```
2. Set locale value at `parameters.yml`

   ```
   locale: es
   ```
3. Set language at base template:

   ```
   <html lang="{{ app.request.locale }}">
   ```
4. Check locale after page loads in Twig template where issue is happening:

   ```
   {{ app.request.locale }} // returns "es" it's right
   ```
5. Clear the cache several/many/manyyyyyyyyyyy times:

   1st approach (didn't work):

   ```
   php app/console cache:clear
   php app/console cache:warmup
   ```

   2nd approach (didn't work):

   ```
   rm -rf /app/cache
   ```

   3th approach (didn't work): cd to `app/cache` and select each file one by one (using mc from Linux) and remove all them including directories by pressing F8
6. Clear browser cache and test in Firefox/Chrome

I've checked the `app/cache` dir under `translations` directory and there is a file `catalogue.es.php` which contains all the translated strings so translation is working.

My translation are defined in a `messages.es.yml` file at `AppBundle/Resources/translations` and this is an example of the content:

```
registro:
    natural:
        panelTitulo: Datos del Usuario
    columnas:
        tipo_usuario: Tipo de Usuario
campos:
    tipoTramite: Tipo de Trámite
```

Then in my view this is how I access those translations:

```
{{'registro.natural.panelTitulo'|trans}}
{{'registro.columnas.tipo_usuario'|trans}}
```

But this, when user is not logged in, does not work, but, if I logged in and try this translation instead:

```
{{'campos.tipoTramite'|trans}}
{{ 'registro.columnas.tipo_usuario'|trans }}
```

and both works (I'm using FOSUserBundle for User management but translations doesn't belongs to any domain, just in the directory I mention earlier) so I'm complete lost since I don't know what else to do. Can any give me some advice around this? Translation only work if user has logged in in a application? I'm doing something wrong? How is that possible?

**Extra information**

This is the relevant part of my `composer.json` file those are the bundles I'm using on my application right now, any one problematic?

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.5.*@dev",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.*@dev",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
    "misd/phone-number-bundle": "~1.0",
    "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "~1.0",
    "h4cc/alice-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "oneup/uploader-bundle": "dev-master",
    "willdurand/js-translation-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "1.0.*@dev"
}
```

Comment: Can you show a little bit more of the context of the template file?

Comment: @WouterJ what you mean with "a little bit more of the context of that template"? Can you clear what you need in order to give you the info?

Comment: @WouterJ take a look to [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12432) it's better explained

Comment: Have you tried to disable FOSUserBundle? Maybe it's some kind of conflict... although I can't really imagine that.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer how is supposed that my application will works with FOSUserBundle disabled? That's part of it and users should be logged in for do things on it so I don't think that's the problem could be something else

Comment: Of course you need FOS... ^^ but i just remembered that they had a translation issue some time ago. And I can't really imagine that your problem has something to do with it, but just to make things clear.

Comment: I went to the trouble of creating a fresh Symfony2 install, added your translation file, set the fallback locale to `es`, and threw your Twig example for both the "secured area" and the unsecured area of the Hello World AcmeDemoBundle apps. With both the user logged in and no user logged in (anonymous), the app correctly translated both samples. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/zpqyNAG.png) and [here](http://i.imgur.com/oPhbzOz.png). I'm not sure how else I can reproduce your problem except for adding in the rest of your bundles.. this will likely take more detective work on your part.

Comment: Can you try `{{'registro.natural.panelTitulo'|trans({}, 'AppBundle') }}`? Obviously clear all your caches again when trying it.

Comment: Pardon, that won't work - try `messages` instead of `AppBundle` and do a search for files named `messages.es.*` in your entire project folder.

Comment: Rename your `messages.es.yml` file to something else and use this as the domain: `{{ 'foo.bar'|trans({}, 'messages_renamed') }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`messages` is a fairly common keyword for a translation domain and I suspect that conflicting bundles are overriding your translation file in certain scenarios. To fix this:

1. Rename your `messages.es.yml` file to `AppBundle.es.yml`
2. Use this format `{{ 'registro.natural.panelTitulo'|trans({}, 'AppBundle') }}` for all usage of your bundle translations, especially when working with Twig files outside of `AppBundle`
3. Clear your caches

Comment: Thanks @sjagr now it works seems like that was  the problems, I can give you the awards right now but as soon as I can I would, thanks for your help

Comment: @ReynierPM It was a long-shot! I'm glad it worked! Don't forget to close your issue on GitHub!

Comment: I have a additional question related, perhaps, to this translation issue, since I'm working with FOSUserBundle I have this in the template where issue was: `{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}` what this code does? Could be this which are causing the issue in first?

Comment: @ReynierPM Potentially! Whatever the `trans_default_domain` is set to is what is called in the `trans` filter! So in essence, if that was set to `FOSUserBundle`, it was as if you were using `{{ 'registro.natural.panelTitulo'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}`. By explicitly defining `AppBundle` in the `trans` filter, it solves this problem as well :) you can leave the `trans_default_domain` be or else you may see other FOSUserBundle translations break.

Comment: any advice on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987149/bazingajstranslationbundle-does-not-translate-strings) topic?