# BazingaJsTranslationBundle does not translate strings

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I'm trying to use [BazingaJsTranslationBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle) for take advance of Symfony2 translations. After read docs this is what I've done:

1. Include needed JS libraries

   ```
   <script src="{{ asset('bundles/bazingajstranslation/js/translator.min.js') }}"></script>
   // Tried this way
   <script src="{{ url('bazinga_jstranslation_js', { 'domain': 'AppBundle' }) }}"></script>

   // Also tried this one
   <script src="{{ url('bazinga_jstranslation_js') }}"></script>
   ```
2. Setup bundle at `config.yml`:

   ```
   bazinga_js_translation:
       locale_fallback:      "%locale%"
       default_domain:       AppBundle
   ```
3. Dump translations using the bazinga supply command:

   ```
   Symfony > bazinga:js-translation:dump
   Installing translation files in /var/www/html/sencamer.dev/web/js directory
   ```
4. Start using translations in JS files:

   ```
   Translator.trans('mensaje.msgAgregarSatisfactorio', {"pronombre": "la", "elemento": "solicitud"}, 'AppBundle')
   ```

   where this is the original string from `AppBundle.es.yml`:

   ```
   msgAgregarSatisfactorio: Se ha creado %pronombre% %elemento% satisfactoriamente.
   ```

   and this is the dump translation at `web\js\translations\AppBundle\es.js`

   ```
   Translator.add("mensajes.msgAgregarSatisfactorio", "Se ha creado %pronombre% %elemento% satisfactoriamente.", "AppBundle", "es");
   ```

When that code is executed I get the untranslated string: `mensaje.msgAgregarSatisfactorio` but not the message, why? What's wrong? This topic is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814240/weird-issue-translations-works-if-logged-in-if-not-then-didnt-work-in-symfony) in somehow, any advice?

As this image shows, there are no Javascript errors on console and also file is loaded and I think it's well formed:

[image]

Comment: Do `.js` files get actually loaded?

Comment: @JovanPerovic yes, they are loaded

Comment: Check out your Javascript console for error messages - put them here

Comment: @sjagr there is no errors at all, see the image I leave on the main post

Comment: Try running `Translator.trans` with those parameters in your question directly in the console. What does it return?

Comment: @sjagr this is the output `"mensaje.msgAgregarSatisfactorio"`

Comment: Is this a typo? `mensajes.msgAgregarSatisfactorio`? You're shuffling `mensaje` and `mensajes` between your `add` and `trans` functions. See: `Translator.add("mensajes.msgAgregarSatisfactorio"` and `Translator.trans('mensaje.msgAgregarSatisfactorio',`

Comment: @sjagr yes, you're right, so simple and I was looking for a bigger error under my code, that's happen to me all the time when I'm writing code at 2AM or 3AM, thanks, if you like answer the question and I'll give your points, once again

Comment: No problem! I'm actually putting a vote in to close the question since it was determined as a typo. It's not a bad thing - it's just that the question is unlikely to help anyone in the future. No need to delete the question though - there's no penalty to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `trans` function:

```
Translator.trans('mensaje.msgAgregarSatisfactorio', {"pronombre": "la", "elemento": "solicitud"}, 'AppBundle')
```

since the message you're trying to access uses the `mensajes` reference:

```
Translator.add("mensajes.msgAgregarSatisfactorio", "Se ha creado %pronombre% %elemento% satisfactoriamente.", "AppBundle", "es");
```